# What is the fastest way to get only time part of datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, time, sql-server-2016

My problem is that we are using `Datetime` column in our database but we need to show our date in different calendar like Hijri or Shamsi With the **Time**.

So with complex query cost of conversion is very high and i need an efficient way to get **Time** and concatenate it with the converted date part.

Right now i am using these approaches

1-

```
CONCAT(dbo.getShamsiDate( JI.Job_start_execution_date ),' ',FORMAT(JI.Job_start_execution_date,'HH:mm:s')) AS [JobStart]

JobStart
1399/05/13 19:25:47
```

2-

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Job_start_execution_date , 108) JobStart;

JobStart
----------
14:43:35
```

My question is this:

**Which one is faster or be suited and is there any faster way?**

Comment: Format is probably the [slowest](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). `CAST(... as Time)` is also a possiblity.

Comment: Agreed that `FORMAT` is likely the slowest. It's "fine" for a single scalar value, but it scales very poorly. If you ever do need formatted strings, and for some reason can't do it in your presentation layer, then `CONVERT` with style codes is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast/convert it to a `time`, as that retain the correct typing (it's still a date and time data type):

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(time(0),datetimevalue), CAST(datetimevalue AS time(3))
```

As the value is a `datetime`, the value will be accurate to 1/300th of a second, however, choose a precision appropriate for your data.